# How do I delete a specific cookie by name in Safari?

Tags: safari, cookies

I opted into an experimental new Stack feature (coming soonish!), and now I want to opt back out. To do so, all I have to do is delete a cookie called `purple`. It should be easy. Just go to Safari preferences, privacy, cookie details, and...

[image]

...hum.

I don't want to delete all of my Stack Exchange cookies, just the one I know the name of. Can I delete this cookie through Safari? If not, where do Safari's cookies live, so I can delete it by hand?

Comment: The *Details* button seems to have been removed from recent version(s) of Safari. I'm running Version 9.1 (11601.5.17.1) on El Capitan.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can still see individual cookies using Safari in developer mode.  Go to **"Safari-->Preferences-->Advanced"** and enable **"Show Develop menu in menu bar"**.  Navigate to the webpage that holds the cookie you are looking to remove.  Go to **Develop** in the menu bar and "**Show web inspector**".  On the left hand side there will be a folder "Cookies" that holds the data from that site.  You can right click them and delete certain ones.

[image]

Comment: What if you don't know what web page, only the domain?

Comment: On the current latest version of macOS Safari (10.1.1), cookies can now be found under the Storage tab.

Answer (score 0):

This works, from 2012, but I just tried it -

http://osxdaily.com/2012/06/10/delete-site-specific-cookies-ios/

Comment: The question refers to MacOS/OS X, not IOS.  Although it didn't say so in text, the screen shot makes it obvious.